# How to turn off multiple desktops on Android 4 (LG Optimus L9 P760)?

Tags: applications, lg

I would like to turn off multiple desktops that are on my Android 4 phone (LG Optimus L9 P760, if that matters). I can switch between them with touch, but I don't need that feature. And most of the time, I use it by mistake (when I want to click an icon close to screen's edge). So it's more like disadvantage for me to have multiple desktops.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any such position in top menu, settings menu etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I've used **Apex Launcher** that can be easily downloaded directly from several sites or with K-droid, so it's a good option for people that don't use Google Play / Google Account. Among its features there are options to change the screens count (I've set it to 1) and increase the grid size.

Vembu pointed out the **Nova Laucher**, which I was unable to test (it seems that working version can be downloaded only from Google Play). Still, it may be an solution for some of you (up-voted).

Answer (score 1):

Try "Nova Launcher" app from the Google play store. The "Nova Launcher" has ability to customize home screens and etc. Try this and check your results.

[Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en_GB)

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately I don't use Google Play and there is no way to download Nova Laucher apk directly (even when I did it after 1 hour of going throw fake links, installed version showed the window with "please download" that redirect to Google Play). Can you suggest me another application?